# How to get only particular fields in response in Struts 2

Tags: java, jquery, regex, json, struts2

I have an action class in which many action methods are defined and appropriate getters and setters methods are also defined. I have some action methods from which I get the data as json  by calling them from jQuery. but when I get the json data it includes all the fields for which getters and setters are defined but i want to get only that field which is filled by that method to which i am calling. for example-

```
public class ApplicantRegistration extends ActionSupport{
private String s1;
private XyzBean bean;
private String s2;
// respective getters and setters....

public String m1(){
// some work
 return SUCCESS;
}

public String m2(){
   //some work
    s2="abc";
    return SUCCESS;
}


}
```

when i call method m2 via jQuery and get json response it gives

```
{
 s1: null,
 bean: null,
 s2:"abc",
 m2: "success",

}
```

but I want only

```
{
 s2:"abc"
}
```

Comment: Are you using json plugin and what is your action configuration?

Comment: yes I am using struts2 json plugin 2.3.12.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `json` result serializes all bean properties specified by the `root` parameter which is set by default to the action. But you can use `includeProperties` parameter of the result to filter only those properties from the `root` that matched regex expressions.

```
@Result(type="json", params = {"includeProperties", "^s2"})
```